# XDocument to Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

This is my Xdocument:

```
<Response>
    <city>
        <CityName>xxx</CityName>
        <CityId>1</CityId>
    </city>
    <city>
        <CityName>yyy</CityName>
        <CityId>2</CityId>
    </city>   
</Response>
```

How can i store this in a `Dictionary(cityname,cityid)`:

```
Dictionary<string, string > dictionary;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var dict = doc.Root.Elements("city")
                   .ToDictionary(c => (string)c.Element("CityName"),
                                 c => (string)c.Element("CityId"));
```

Tricky question - why do you want `CityId` as a string, not an `int`?

Comment: thank you very mush. just i'm going to display CityId. so type is not matter

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        dictionary.Add(node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText, node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText);

    }
```